# How to Restore photos on SD card

Tags: restore

I deleted 40 some photos from my SD card in my camera.  I thought I saved them on my desktop.  Using 12.04 LTS.  Is there a way to restore the photos??  My wife is pissed.  Nothing has been over written on the card.

Thanks

Answer (score 99):

### [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) / [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)

Yes, use the tool [`photorec`](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec); you'll be able to recover pretty much any file.

You should make sure that the SD card is read only as writing to it can corrupt any possibility of recovering data.

In Ubuntu, open a terminal and run:

```
$ sudo apt install testdisk
$ sudo photorec
```

Comment: Just tried it, it works great, recovered all files on sdcard.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install testdisk` will install the `photorec` binary.

Comment: Worked like a magic for me.

Comment: Wow, lifesaver! Restored almost all the lost photos!

Comment: You can rename the pictures to their original naming format by using the date and time contained in their EXIF data (if present). I have posted instructions [here](https://superuser.com/a/1703412/109947).