# How to recover Files from a coruppted Micro SD card?

Tags: usb, sd-card

I am having a problem with my Samsung Micro SD card (in particular, a Samsung 32GB Evo mircoSDHC UHS-1 Grade I Class 10 Card).

I use the card in my 8GB Motorola Moto G 4G which is running Android 5.1. Unfortunately the card recently stopped working, and I am not sure why. I bought both in June.

One day I simply noticed that the card was no longer mounted to the phone. I am now unable to mount the card onto the phone. There is data stored on the card that I would very much like to recover before I format the card.

My computer is running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, and I figure that it will be easier to recover the data on my computer than on the phone itself.

My monitor (Dell, I don't know the model) has a card reader, in particular a Standard Microsystems Corp. 9-in-2 Card Reader (and the Micro SD card came with an SD adapter). The card reader is found by my machine when I run lsusb.

When I insert the card (in it's adaptor) into the Card Reader it is not detected by my machine.

(I have a laptop which runs Windows, and when I insert the card into the card reader on that, it is found by Windows, but I cannot open the device to see what files are on the card).

I have tried searching for answers to my problem already, but I have not found exactly what I am looking for.

I found [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224333/why-does-ubuntu-not-detect-my-sd-card) [similar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330568/how-to-restore-photos-on-sd-card) questions, but the former was too technical for me (I tried to read the documentation attached, but I am not an expert, and my machine is owned by the university, so I did not want to run anything without being sure of what it is doing and that it is safe), while the later assumed that the files have already been deleted.

I also found [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) info on GUN ddrescue, which may help me to recover the files, once I can detect the card.

Ideally what I am asking for is a way to force ubuntu to read the card, and to copy any files on the card that it can to my machine as a back-up.

I would then be able to format the card, and start over, and hopefully it would be read by my phone again.

For the record, I am trying to recover image files (personal photos which I would like back) and audio files (recordings of work meetings which I need back).

And before Captain Hindsight mentions it, I did back up (some of) my data once in the past 6 months, on the 18th November, but obviously I don't do it frequently enough (and I didn't back up the photos)!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I am sometime facing the same issue after building android for odroid card and badly modify things.

When trying to recover the card, it is sometime quite difficult, but i have discover that using disks app in ubuntu may help : select your SD card and click the gear in right vue of app. Select "format..." and choose 'don't overwrite...' and 'mbr'.

For me, when the card is partitioned, it recovers partition table, and the SD card can be read again.
I think you should run a linux image (ubuntu for example) and run it as a live USB key / CD from your laptop, which will be better for card reader.

You may want to save your data before :

```
sudo dd if=/dev/<SD_path> of=/home/<user>/sdcard.bin
```