# unusable micro sd card after getting pulled from pc

Tags: sd-card

so i have a micro sdcard i use for my hacked 3ds, recently i pulled it from the console and plugged it into ubuntu and made some changes, when i went to plug it back into the console it complained that it couldn't be read. in the past i've reloaded a backup but this time i forgot and my files are completely locked up again. this has been getting on my nerves and i don't want to lose save files, how can i recover the files and not format the card as well as prevent this issue in the future. if any more info is needed feel free to ask and i will happily provide

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover Files from a coruppted Micro SD card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723350/how-to-recover-files-from-a-coruppted-micro-sd-card)

Comment: I have never been able to recover a bricked uSD card. Good luck with the warranty.